# Is there a better way to handle font_face (google fonts) than this?

Tags: font-face

In trying to get google fonts (font_face) working with IE7, 8, 9, Chrome and Firefox I ended up with a bit of a convoluted mess of files stored locally, on a remote server, as ttf, eot and woff. Is there a better/easier way to get them working for all these browsers? This is what I ended up doing to get it to work.

This is the html

```
<link href="Untitled_1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Untitled_1_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This is the first css (untitled_1.css):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bangers';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bangers'), local('Bangers-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/bangers/v4/DqeGA7eaz0hhOYTfkeJBIA.woff') format('woff');
src: url('Bangers.ttf'); /* for chrome/webkit */
```

}

This is the second (untitled_1_ie.css):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bangers';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url('Bangers.eot');    /* ie9 */
src: url('Bangers.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
```

}

IE9 would only work with a locally stored version of the eot (or ttf) due to 'no cross-domain custom fonts' error, IE7/8 would only work with eot and Chrome would not work with woff (the default produced by google fonts website).

Thanks.